# How to unset all upper array values from a specific location in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a small task in php. I have these two arrays.

Images

```
Array
(
    [0] => 420157_NpFQlK
    [1] => 420157_5yVlp9
    [2] => 420157_hqioBU
    [3] => 420157_a5wbZB
)
```

Levels

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 150
    [3] => 200
    [4] => 250
    [5] => 300
    [6] => 350
    [7] => 400
)
```

Now i need to display result like this

Images

```
Array
(
    [0] => 420157_NpFQlK
    [1] => 420157_5yVlp9
    [2] => 420157_hqioBU
    [3] => 420157_a5wbZB
)
```

Levels

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 150

)
```

i want to unset all the upper levels. I mean if count of images array is 4 the unset levels[3](4th index) and all upper levels. How can i do it in shortest php script?

Comment: If all your keys are numeric, 0-based, continuous, try `$level=array_slice($level,0,count($image)-1)`.

Comment: Its just simple calculation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), for example:

```
$levels = array_slice($levels, 0, count($images) - 1);
```

You should pay some attention to the arguments so that this works exactly how you want it to in edge cases as well (for example what happens if `$images` is empty?)

Comment: I find this as the most programmatic solution because passing it to level is also what i wanted and it has saved a line. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use array_slice for that :D

```
$subArray = array_slice($arr,0,$index);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php array_slice($levels, 0,count($images)-1); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use array_slice.

```
$count =3;
$slice_array=array_slice($levels,0,$count);
```